# METAFONT bitmap latin glyphs

Tags: metafont, latin-modern

I'm building a font format that integrates multiple point size bitmap glyphs. On eInk monochrome displays, bitmap fonts are still the best way to get reasonably good characters. I've been able to use Computer Modern fonts, merging parts of TFM and PK files with success. You can find it [here](https://github.com/turgu1/ibmf). A C++ class translates Unicode characters to the proper sequence to create accented Latin-1 and Latin-A characters using the glyphs available in the Computer Modern fonts (Serif, Sans, and Typewriter).

Many glyphs are not available, as some specific characters are not present in Computer Modern. I'm thinking of creating those glyphs, but I'm wondering if there are any existing METAFONT-oriented fonts that supply all the glyphs from U+0020 to U+017F?

Comment: most will be in the ec fonts

Comment: Thanks David. I will check the ec font.